# Multicolumn overflow

Tags: multicol

I'm compiling a list of theorems and definitions from a math textbook (Mörters and Peres's "Brownian Motion"). Each item on the document (e.g. a definition, a theorem, a comment) opens with a title or a succinct description. As [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4imrb.jpg) demonstrates, comment 1.4's title overflows into the adjacent column. Why does it happen? Other items on the page have equally long titles, and yet they wrap properly. Following is a code listing of the beginning of the document up to (and including) the shrewish item.

```
\title{Brownian Motion}
\date{}

\documentclass[8pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=0.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}    % needed for subequations
\usepackage{amsfonts}   % needed for $\mathbb{R}$
\usepackage{dsfont} % needed for $\mathds{1}$
\usepackage{graphicx}   % needed for figures
\usepackage{color}      % needed if color is used in text
\usepackage{hyperref}   % needed for hypertext links, including those to external documents and URLs
\usepackage{multicol}   % needed for the multicols environment

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{theorem}[definition]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{theonition}[definition]{Theorem and Definition}
\newtheorem{proposition}[definition]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lemma}[definition]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{example}[definition]{Example}
\newtheorem{counterexample}[definition]{Counterexample}
\newtheorem{comment}[definition]{Comment}
\newtheorem{assumption}[definition]{Assumption}
\newtheorem{corollary}[definition]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{notation}[definition]{Notation}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
A list of definitions, theorems and examples taught in the course ``Brownian Motion''.
\end{abstract}

\begin{multicols}{3}

\begin{comment}
  Lecture No. 1
\end{comment}

\section{Chapter 1. Brownian motion as a random function}

\subsection{Stochastic processes}

\begin{definition}[Stochastic process; p. 7]
  A \em{stochastic process} is a family $\left\{B\left(t\right) : t \geq 0\right\}$ of (uncountably many) random variables $\omega \mapsto B\left(t,\omega\right)$, defined on a single probability space $\left(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P\right)$.
\end{definition}

\begin{comment}[Sample path interpretation of a stochastic process; p. 7]
  A stochastic process can be interpreted as a random function with the sample functions defined by $t \mapsto B\left(t,\omega\right)$.
\end{comment}

\begin{definition}[Finite-dimensional distributions of a stochastic process; p. 8]
  By the \em{finite-dimensional distributions} of a stochastic process $\left\{B\left(t\right) : t \geq 0\right\}$ we mean the laws of all the finite dimensional random vectors $\left(B\left(t_1\right), B\left(t_2\right), \dots, B\left(t_n\right)\right)$ for all $0\leq t_1\leq t_2\leq \dots \leq t_n$.
\end{definition}

\begin{comment}[Finite-dimensional distributions; p. 8]
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item To describe these joint laws it suffices to describe the joint law of $B\left(0\right)$ and the increments
    \begin{multline*}
    \left(B\left(t_1\right) - B\left(0\right), \dots,\right. \\
      \left.B\left(t_n\right) - B\left(t_{n - 1}\right)\right)
    \end{multline*}
    for all $0 \leq t_1\leq \dots \leq t_n$.
    \item The set
      $$
      \left\{\omega \in \Omega : t\mapsto B\left(t,\omega\right)\textrm{ continuous}\right\}
      $$
      is in general not in the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the random vectors $\left(B\left(t_1\right), B\left(t_2\right),\dots,B\left(t_n\right)\right),\ n\in\mathbb{N}_1$.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{comment}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't start `\begin{enumerate}` immediately after the `comment`. Try putting some text there (just before `\begin{enumerate}`.

Comment: @HarishKumar: Thanks. I've just realized it. Why is it so?

Comment: You can also put `enumerate` inside the `minipage`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem happens when the item contains the `enumerate` environment and nothing else. Once I've added a few words of text before the enumeration, the title started wrapping properly. I don't understand why this happens, but at least I've managed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with *multicols*, and your remark helped me to solve it. The problem occured when the first element of each line was inside a formatting diretive, e.g:

```
\normalsize{\emph{{\textbf{Isoetes schweinfurthii}}} A.Braun ex Baker}
\linebreak
```

Adding extra text at the begining, without formatting, was a possible workaround. However, in my case, the problem occured because the **spaceskip** directive, defined at document level, was conflicting with *multicols* :

```
\spaceskip 0.5 em \relax
```

Removing this directive, and using **\raggedright** instead, solved the problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!